# GWT (2.7.0 -> 2.8.2) Incorrectly typed data found for annotation

Tags: maven, gwt

I am trying to migrate from GWT 2.7.0 to GWT 2.8.2 version. Unfortunately, I ran into some problems. I keep getting `AnnotationTypeMismatchException`.

Relevant pom parts:

```
<properties>
    <gwt.version>2.8.2</gwt.version>  <!-- changed from 2.7.0 -->
    <gwtp.version>1.6</gwtp.version> <!-- changed from 1.4 -->
</properties>
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${gwt.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        <version>${gwt.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
<plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${gwt.version}</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compile</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>                    
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    ...
</plugins>
```

Exception:

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project web: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.annotation.AnnotationTypeMismatchException: Incorrectly typed data found for annotation element public abstract java.lang.String com.gwtplatform.dispatch.annotation.GenDispatch.serviceName() (Found data of type java.lang.String) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project web: Fatal error compiling
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Fatal error compiling
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:796)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.CompilerException: java.lang.annotation.AnnotationTypeMismatchException: Incorrectly typed data found for annotation element public abstract java.lang.String com.gwtplatform.dispatch.annotation.GenDispatch.serviceName() (Found data of type java.lang.String)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:191)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile(JavacCompiler.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:785)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.annotation.AnnotationTypeMismatchException: Incorrectly typed data found for annotation element public abstract java.lang.String com.gwtplatform.dispatch.annotation.GenDispatch.serviceName() (Found data of type java.lang.String)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:469)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:132)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:126)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.annotation.AnnotationTypeMismatchException: Incorrectly typed data found for annotation element public abstract java.lang.String com.gwtplatform.dispatch.annotation.GenDispatch.serviceName() (Found data of type java.lang.String)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.model.AnnotationProxyMaker$ValueVisitor$1AnnotationTypeMismatchExceptionProxy.generateException(AnnotationProxyMaker.java:264)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationInvocationHandler.invoke(AnnotationInvocationHandler.java:83)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25.serviceName(Unknown Source)
    at com.gwtplatform.dispatch.annotation.processor.GenDispatchProcessor.process(GenDispatchProcessor.java:52)
    at com.gwtplatform.dispatch.annotation.processor.GenProcessor.process(GenProcessor.java:78)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:793)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:722)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1700(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:97)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1029)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1163)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1108)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:824)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:439)
    ... 28 more
```

Since stack trace does not reach any of my classes, it's hard to judge what might be causing this. The only place I could think of is this (since stack trace mentions GenDispatch) :

```
import com.gwtplatform.dispatch.annotation.GenDispatch;
import com.gwtplatform.dispatch.annotation.In;
import com.gwtplatform.dispatch.annotation.Out;
import com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rpc.shared.UnsecuredActionImpl;

@GenDispatch(isSecure = false, serviceName = UnsecuredActionImpl.DEFAULT_SERVICE_NAME)
public class SomeAction {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some RPC classes were using incorrect import, which worked with GWTP 1.4, but did not work with GWTP 1.6.

changed

```
import com.gwtplatform.dispatch.shared.UnsecuredActionImpl;
```

to

```
import com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rpc.shared.UnsecuredActionImpl;
```